# function var in closure cause error on Firefox7/8

Tags: javascript, firefox, closures

code as below:

```
    function(){
        log1();
        function log1(evt) {
            alert("1");
        }
    }();
```

on firefox 8, nothing happend, 
and error **log1 is not defined** shown in firebug console.
The code could be executed succeeded on Chrome and IE9.

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net to validate your script. Only well formed javascript executes on all the major browsers. This works http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/ck2hV/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can not be  executed.
you can make it like this way:

```
(function(){
    log1();
    function log1(evt) {
        alert("1");
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Firefox 8.0 like this:

```
(function (){     
    log1();         
    function log1(evt) {
        alert("1");         
    }     
})();
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2QYHJ/